# Issue with Aligning or Positioning Flutter Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want the Container attached to the body of the Scaffold to occupy the space of it's child, which is the Padding widget in this case.

```
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      appBar: AppBar(
        // backgroundColor: AppColors.grey,
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          boxShadow: kBoxShadow,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(kSpacingUnit * 3.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              EmailSignInForm(),
              SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit * 4.0),
              SocialMediaLoginWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Below is the screenshot for the above code:

[image]

But I also want the padding widget to be pushed to the bottom of the screen. To achieve this I wrapped the Padding widget with the Expanded widget, and later wrapped the Expanded widget with a Column widget, as shown below:

```
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      appBar: AppBar(
        // backgroundColor: AppColors.grey,
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          boxShadow: kBoxShadow,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(kSpacingUnit * 3.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    EmailSignInForm(),
                    SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit * 4.0),
                    SocialMediaLoginWidget(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Now that the contents of the Padding widget have got pushed to the bottom of the screen, but the Expanded widget, tries to occupy all the available space. I don't want this to happen.

I don't want the height of the Padding widget to increase. Below is the screenshot after updating the code:

[image]

Another issue that's concerning me is, where should I be adding the SingleChildScrollView, as I would experience the "Bottom overflowed by -- px" error when the user would tap on the TextFormFields to input the email and password.

I did raise this issue earlier as well but wasn't much luck, so thought would organize the code and explain it in detail so that it would be easy for others to understand and help.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

**AFTER APPLYING SOLUTION SUGGESTED BY @SoundConception**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your Column widget :

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
```

Comment: I did try your solution as well Fatiha, but no luck with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example you have:

```dart
      ...
      body: Container(
        ...
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(kSpacingUnit * 3.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              ...
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

The `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` specifies that the `Column` should be as small as possible in height, effectively shrink wrapping it to the height of its children.

The `Padding` just adds the specified dp of padding around `Column` widget.

This means the child of the `Container` has a fixed height equal to the sum of the `Column` children heights plus `(kSpacingUnit * 3.0)` dp of padding top and bottom.
Since the `Container` child height is fixed, the `Container` will size itself to the height of it's child.

In your second code example you have:

```dart
      body: Container(
        ...
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(kSpacingUnit * 3.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ...
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Here the outermost `Column` has a single child that is an `Expanded` which means this will take up all the available room in the `Column`.
The innermost `Column` has `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` meaning its children will align to the bottom of the `Column`. The height of your `Padding` has not expanded.

You ask about using a `SingleChildScrollView`. I assume you want the white background decoration to remain stationary, and only the contents of the `Column` should be able to scroll.
Try something like the following:

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          boxShadow: kBoxShadow,
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(kSpacingUnit * 3.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                EmailSignInForm(),
                SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit * 4.0),
                SocialMediaLoginWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

### Note: You'll need to make sure your `EmailSignInForm()` and `SocialMediaLoginWidget()` do not have unbound height.

My guess is your `EmailSignInForm()` probably utilises a `Column`. If so set it's `mainAxisSize` to `min`.

Comment: Thank you so much @SoundConception for your elaborate explanation. Yes, you guessed it right they both utilize the `Column` widget and the `mainAxisSize` was missing for both `EmailSignInForm()` and `SocialMediaLoginWidget()` I did try setting the `mainAxisSize` to `min` for both  `EmailSignInForm()` and `SocialMediaLoginWidget()`. It's still the same, it occupies the entire space. Not sure what's causing this issue. I have attached the screenshot after updating the code. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: That's good that you've now set the `mainAxisSize` to `min` for `EmailSignInForm()` and `SocialMediaLoginWidget()`, but you should also at the same time *remove* `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` from their parent `Column` as per my last code sample in my answer. This is currently making the children go to the *end* of the main *vertical* axis, in other words, the *bottom*.

Comment: Thanks @SoundConception I have removed the `mainAxisAlignment` from it's parent `Column` but still the output is the same. I'm not sure, what's causing this.